# Pointer Memory Leak

Tags: c++

My pointer p is inside a function, will i get memory leak with this code.

```
for(k=0;k< 3;k++)
{

    int *p=NULL;
    int val = bBreak[k+1] - bBreak[k];

    p = new int [val+1];
    p = &buff[bBreak[k]];

    for(int i=0;i< val;i++)
        {

            cout<<"\n"<<p[i]<<endl;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes, new (no placement) without delete is memory-leak.

Comment: You allocate something with `new`. You never call `delete`.

So yes, you leak memory.

Comment: Every `new`, requires a `delete` and every `new[]` requires a `delete[]`.

Comment: This looks very much like a construed homework problem.

Comment: @jalf That's not really the definition of a leak that you want to use; there *are* cases where one might have a `new` without a corresponding `delete`.  The fact that he has no pointer to the allocated memory is more significant, since that means that he cannot possibly use it.  (Still, the fact that it is just one allocation, and not in repeated code, means that it isn't really a leak.)

Comment: @James: i would tend to disagree even with the apparent assumptions you use. even a smallish leak is troublesome, in that it distract by showing up in a leak detector. however, the OP stated that this code is in a function, which presumably might be called a zillion times each second, so by any reasonable definition it's a potential big leak.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: It depends. It would definitely *NOT* show up in valgrind, which can be considered the canonical leak detector. Valgrind checks whether there is still a pointer to the memory when the program exits, exactly because especially C modules never bother freeing memory they malloc during startup. It's not common in C++ where destructors are used to take care of that.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It *IS* repeated. It's in a loop with 3 iterations. And since it's out of context, we don't know whether it's not in a function called million times. Though I do agree that one-time new without delete does not have to be a problem.

Comment: It should be pointed out, that this code is **very bad C++ style**. You should not be using naked `new` in application code. Use `vectors`, `unique_ptr` (auto_ptr if stuck in C++03), `shared_ptr` with `make_shared` and such to ensure memory management.

Comment: @Alf (and others): you're right.  This is in a loop, in an unnamed function, so it probably is a leak.  My comments in the parentheses are wrong.  (For the rest of what I wrote, you really don't have a choice.  The standard more or less requires `std::cout` et al. to allocate memory that is never freed, and it's not a leak if a static object or a singleton does likewise.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: IMO it doesn't need to be repeated in order to be a leak. It's a leak, because he allocates memory which doesn't get freed. It's a small, harmless leak because the program is short-running and it (in this case) it only runs a few iterations, but it's still a leak. Of course, there are cases (smart pointers) where you have `new` calls without an *explicit* `delete`. But the `delete` is still there *somewhere*.

Comment: @jaik That's not the definition of leak.  A leak is something that continues without stopping.  Singleton's will usually allocate memory which is never freed; objects like `std::cout` and `std::cin` do as well.  As long as the allocation is a one-time event, and the memory continues to be used, you can't consider it a leak.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You never free the memory. You should call `delete/delete[]` for every piece of memory you allocate with `new/new[]`.

Comment: The answer should be just "yes"

Comment: @Alf But the system here won't let him post unless he has a minimum number of characters.  Three's not enough.

Comment: Exactly ... you have to write *something* :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will

```
p = new int [val+1]; //allocate array on the heap
p = &buff[bBreak[k]]; //new allocated array is leaked because you lost the pointer to it
//and you are not able to call 'delete[]' to free the memory
```

Generally, every call to operator `new` should be paired with call of operator `delete` or `delete[]`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You must `delete` every memory you allocate with `new`.

```
p = new int [val+1];
p = &buff[bBreak[k]]; // here you lose track of the memory you've just allocated
```

If you don't want to do memory management by-hand, use a `std::vector<int>`.